# Typescript function arguments type inference issue

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typescript-typings, vue-composition-api, tsc

I have this piece of code here:

```
export default function (triggerEl: Ref<HTMLDivElement>, contentEl: Ref<HTMLDivElement>, placement: Ref<Placement> | Placement = 'auto', offset: Ref<number> | number = 0) {

  placement = ref(placement) as Ref<Placement>
  offset = ref(offset)

  const { top: triggerTop, right: triggerRight, bottom: triggerBottom, left: triggerLeft, width: triggerWidth, height: triggerHeight } = useElementBounding(triggerEl)
  const { top: contentTop, right: contentRight, bottom: contentBottom, left: contentLeft, width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight } = useElementBounding(contentEl)


  const position = computed<PopperPosition>(() => {
    let top = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
    let left = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER

    if (placement.value === 'top') {
      top = triggerTop.value - contentHeight.value - offset.value
      left = triggerLeft.value + triggerWidth.value / 2 - contentWidth.value / 2
    }

    return {
      top,
      left,
    }
  })



  return  null
}
```

[image]

**I have converted the 'placement' and 'offset' parameters to their corresponding 'Ref' type, but the below code still thinks they are type Ref | number, so it complains, but they actually never would be number type.**

**How would I solve the typing check issue here ???**

Comment: I can do this to avoid the TS compile error: '(placement as Ref<Placement>).value', but it will be very tedious, since I would need to apply this workaround everywhere. Isn't TS smart enough to know that the 'placement' has been converted to Ref type at the very top already ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the source that messes TS's inference is located on lines 21 and 22(reassigning variable values):

```
placement = ref(placement) as Ref<Placement>
offset = ref(offset)
```

I suggest creating new variables instead, so the final code will look like this:

```
export default function (triggerEl: Ref<HTMLDivElement>, contentEl: Ref<HTMLDivElement>, placement: Ref<Placement> | Placement = 'auto', offset: Ref<number> | number = 0) {

  const placementRef = ref(placement)
  const offsetRef = ref(offset)

  const { top: triggerTop, right: triggerRight, bottom: triggerBottom, left: triggerLeft, width: triggerWidth, height: triggerHeight } = useElementBounding(triggerEl)
  const { top: contentTop, right: contentRight, bottom: contentBottom, left: contentLeft, width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight } = useElementBounding(contentEl)


  const position = computed<PopperPosition>(() => {
    let top = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
    let left = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER

    if (placementRef.value === 'top') {
      top = triggerTop.value - contentHeight.value - offsetRef.value
      left = triggerLeft.value + triggerWidth.value / 2 - contentWidth.value / 2
    }

    return {
      top,
      left,
    }
  })



  return  null
}
```

Comment: yep, that's a reasonable workaround for this scenario since the ref method would return the same reference if the passed in parameter is already a "ref", but there would be some cases that you wouldn't want to create new variables, just wondering wouldn't TS compiler knows that it has been re-assigned ??

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure whether TS compiler knows if a value has been re-assigned, but as we can see from your example, it doesn't, so if you stick with reassigning value approach you need to cast the variable's type every time you interact with it, e.g. `placement as Ref<Placement>`

Comment: Thanks mate, at least this "const placementRef = ref(placement)" solves my current problem, probably it doesn't make much sense of re-assigning passed in reference instead of creating new ones.